# JSON Array: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, arrays, json

i tried to get some data with php, json from cubesql database in php. sql statement is working correct.

`var_dump($result)`:

> $array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["RA_Name"]=> string(7) "Muster" } }

now i'd like to get just "Muster" with echo command.

looking at this post ([Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636826/notice-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-error)) i tried it like that:

```
echo $rs[0]->RA_Name;
```

but with that, i get just:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...

what did i wrong here?
thanks for any help.

daniel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->` is for objects, but you have an array.

try this:

```
echo $rs[0]["RA_Name"];
```

Comment: Great, thank you very much. i searched about more than 2 hours for that thing.