# How to update input field values in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, user-input

I am a beginner in Codeigniter and using version 3
I am performing update operation  so I have store data and now I have created a separate form for update
and want to set this form inputs values that are stored in databases

**My View (update.php)**

````
```<div class="form-group"> 
<label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label>
 <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'title', 'placeholder'=>'Enter title',
 'class'=>'form-control col- md-5',
 'value'=>set_value('title','$post->title')]);?>
 </div>```
````

---

**My COntroller**

```
public function update($id)
    {

        $this->load->model('queries');
    $postt=$this->queries->getSinglePosts($id); 

    $post=$postt->title;

        $this->load->view('update',['post'=>$post]);

    }
```

**My Model**

public function getSinglePosts($id)
{
$query=$this->db->get_where('tbl_posts',array('id'=>$id));

```
        if ($query->num_rows() >0 ) {
        return $query->row();
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Notice: Trying to get property of non-object error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22636826/notice-trying-to-get-property-of-non-object-error)

Comment: my input fieldis here: <div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Title</label>
   <?php echo form_input(['name'=>'title','class'=>'form-control',

      'value'=>set_value('title','$post->title')]);?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you've used `set_value('title','$post->title')]);` in your view file, I think you should remove this line from your controller `$post=$postt->title;` and you should pass the whole of `$postt` variable to your view (make sure that the `$postt` is not an array of objects).